# GroupBy in LINQ to DataSet

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, group-by, linq-to-dataset

**Background**:

I'm importing data from a MySQL database into a SQL-Server database(for reports and later a SSAS-Cube). I want to normalize the data at the same time. I want to group repeating `Ticket_IDs` to one record in a table `Contact` with other useful informations and leave the rawdata in the sub-table `ContactDetail`(with foreignkey to Contact).  Hence every record in `Contact` has a unique `Ticket_ID`.

I've decided to use strong typed datasets for the import. Now i'm  wondering what's the best way to detect if i've already added a Ticket_ID. I could check for it in every loop(~100000 records) but i'm assuming that there is a better/faster way.

Simplified sample-data:

```
Ticket_ID    ID     fiContact
89442226     1      1
89442226     2      1
89442226     3      1
89442261     4      2
89442261     5      2
89442354     6      3
89442359     7      4
89442359     8      4
89442367     9      5
89442504     10     6
```

This should be the `Contact`-table

```
Ticket_ID    idContact
89442226     1
89442261     2
89442354     3
89442359     4
89442367     5
89442504     6
```

**Question**:

Is it possible with LINQ/LINQ-to-DataSet to group by Ticket_ID and get a list of ContactDetailRows for every ContactRow? I know there is a [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)-Extension, but i'm unsure how to use and if it does what i need(keep the ContactDetail-Rows, f.e. like a dicitonary with Ticket_ID as key and a `List(of EmailRow)` as value).

This is what i have(simplified):

```
    For Each srcEmail In src.email 'i want to group src.email by Ticket_ID'
        'so far i check for existence in every loop'
        Dim res = From c In dest.Contact
               Where c.Ticket_ID = srcEmail.ticket_id
        If Not res.Any Then
            'create new Contact
            Dim newContact = Me.dest.Contact.NewContactRow
            newContact.Ticket_ID = srcEmail.ticket_id
            ' ..... '
            dest.Contact.AddContactRow(newContact)
        End If
        'TODO: create ContactDetail row and add it to the DataTable '
    Next
```

- `src`: typed DataSet(MySQL)
- `src.email`: typed DataTable  => into `ContactDetail`
- `dest`: typed DataSet(SQL-Server)
- `dest.Contact` typed DataTable
- `dest.ContactDetail` typed DataTable with fk to `Contact`

I would prefer VB.NET because i'm yet not as familiar with LINQ and the Syntax is quite different in C#.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Magnus i've get it going in the following way:

```
Dim emailsPerTicketID = src.email.ToLookup(Function(email) email.ticket_id)
For Each ticket In emailsPerTicketID
    'create new Contact
    Dim newContact = Me.dest.Contact.NewContactRow
    newContact.Ticket_ID = ticket.Key
    newContact.CreatedAt = ticket.First().modified_time
    ' ...... '
    dest.Contact.AddContactRow(newContact)
    'TODO: add now all EmailRows'
    For Each emailRow In ticket
       Dim newContactDetail = dest.ContactDetail.NewContactDetailRow
       newContactDetail.ContactRow = newContact
       newContactDetail.Interaction = emailRow.interaction
       ' .... '
       dest.ContactDetail.AddContactDetailRow(newContactDetail)
    Next
Next
```

I will have a look if this is faster than the iterating approach with a HashSet to detect if the contact was already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx)(like a dictionary but with key/Collection instead) would be a good solution for you. something like this:

```
var lookup = ds.Tables["src"].AsEnumerable().ToLookup(x => x.Field<int>("Ticket_ID"));
foreach (var row in ds.Tables["dest"].AsEnumerable())
{
    if(!lookup.Contains(row.Field<int>("Ticket_ID ")))
    {
        //create new Contact
    }
    else
    {
        //do other struff
    }
}
```

If you need any help translating any of the syntax to VB comment me.

Comment: Thanks. I've translated it to VB.NET/typed `DataSet` myself(see my edit). I'll test if this is faster than iterating and checking with a HashSet like Matt suggested. Lookup was exactly was i was looking for.

Comment: @Tim Great! Let me know how your tests turn out.

Answer (score 1):

My VB is rusty, but here's a shot at it:

```
Dim ticketGroups = From c in dest.Contact
                    Group c By Ticket_ID = c.Ticket_ID 
                    Into Tickets = Group

For Each ticketGroup In ticketGroups
    For Each ticket in ticketGroup.Tickets
        ' Create the row, add it, etc.
        Dim newContact = Me.dest.Contact.NewContactRow
        newContact.Ticket_ID = ticketGroup.Ticket_ID
        ' .... '
        dest.Contact.AddContactRow(newContact)
    Next
Next
```

Alternatively, if you want to check it every time through the loop, you could use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), just adding the ticket ID to the hashset each time through and then checking for its presence via the `Contains` method. That would be faster than what you're doing, but I suspect the LINQ grouping will be faster than the HashSet.

Comment: Thank you. But that would group all email-rows to unique email-rows according to the Ticket_ID. What i needed was a way to group these rows by Ticket_Id but keep all rows, like a dictionary with `Ticket_ID` as key and a `List(of EmaiRows)` as value. Just what @Magnus approach with [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) does.

Comment: Sorry, my example code did not make this clear, but it _does_ keep all rows. Check the ticketGroup.Tickets property. I'll edit the code. (Magnus of course is also correct.) :)